# Leader-shortcut produces extra w motion?

Tags: vim

I have, among hundreds others, these lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
let mapleader = ','   
nnoremap <leader>w :w<CR>
```

When I hit <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> in sequence, it saves the current buffer.
However, it also performs the action tied to <kbd>w</kbd>, which is `jump forward by word`.

In other words, when I hit  <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, it saves and jumps one word forward.
Is there a workaround to this?

**Update:**
`:verbose nmap ,w`

yields

`n  ,w          * :w<CR>         <Space>`, *Last set from ~/.vimrc* .

Comment: Please do `:verbose nmap ,w` to determine where and what `,w` are mapped to. It is likely that you have another mapping that is coming into play here as I have tested you mapping w/o any issues

Comment: That shouldn't happen, but I'm missing stuff. Does this also happen with the default Leader? And shouldn't the title say "produces extra w motion"?!

Comment: Thank you Ingo, I recalled the title might have been wrong after I had moved away from the WiFi hotspot, it's fixed now. I have not yet tried this with the original leader.
Peter, I posted the output in the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have trailing whitespace in your mapping definition, so Vim actually executes this:

```
:w<CR><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space><Space>
```

So, it only appears like an (approximate) _w_ord motion.

The fix is easy: Just remove the trailing whitespace. Also, you shouldn't use `" Comments` after a mapping.

A plugin like my [ShowTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) can help you prevent such errors in the future.

Comment: If one doesn't need the extra functionality provided by the ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin, it's also possible to visualize those characters using the `'list'` and `'listchars'` options.  Something like `set list listchars+=trail:-`.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I do indeed have some comments in that way, but I will change that. I'm not on my work-station right now, but will accept the answer when I can confirm it works. Thanks!

Comment: @krystah its definitely this you can see all the extra whitespace in the question too.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm it, bear with me :) The answer was correct. Thanks as always, Ingo!